# In Eclipse, how to find all java synchronized blocks/methods that lock on instances of a particular class

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse for java development, I want to locate all synchronized methods/blocks that lock on the monitor of an instance of class ClassA. How to do so?

Comment: It sounds scary to me that your project has so many synchronized blocks on different objects that this becomes a problem.

Comment: I searched with keyword "synchronized", about 800 matches in my project. I guess there should be a better way than going through them all.

Comment: 800! What the.. This seem a bit much to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse only offer text search. What you are asking for would require some sort of compiler like support to evaluate the type of object you sync on.

As a workaround you could add comments to the synchronized statements that explains the syncobjects class.

```
synchronized(nobodyKnowsMyName)  // sync(Rumpelstiltskin)
```

This will be an effort but you get what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I've got 800 sync blocks/methods in my projects, adding comments is as time-consuming as manually checking every synchronization block/method. Is there any alternatives, maybe not using eclipse?

Comment: None that I know of (which doesn't mean there is none)

Answer (score 1):

I've solved a similar but simpler problem, which is "How to get Eclipse to find all synchronized blocks locking on a given lock".

Though this is kind of a trivial solution, I'm posting since I think it's an interesting problem and have wondered if there's a better way or an IDE that helped more here. (This isn't quite an answer, but too long for a comment.)

This approach is simply:

1. Create a public Lock class for just this purpose, **MySpecialLock**, and don't define any methods on it.
2. Use it like this:

   ```
   MySpecialLock lock = getTheParticularInstanceInSomeDomainSpecificWay();
   synchronized (lock) { ...  }
   ```
3. Now you can use Eclipse's Java Search for references option, (mouse shortcut by right-clicking on **MySpecialLock** and in the context menu select *References->Workspace*; keyboard shortcut is ***Ctrl+Shift+G*** on Windows).   Every hit now is a synchronized block, since there's really nothing else to do with this

   That doesn't help though if your lock though is a ClassA with other methods, only some of which are synchronized.  Will leave it to you, depending on your code structure, to decide if this approach is at all worth considering refactoring for.

Comment: I think polymorphism is the problem. What if I start passing MySpecialLock around as Object, and then synchronize on it?

Comment: That sounds like it aligns with the general idea enough to help.     I guess if you have a lot of intermediate layers through which you pass MySpecialLock it might leave you with a little more "noise" to filter through to get to the synchronized blocks.     But maybe that's worth it given the design of the code in relation to the scope of each lock instance, only you'd know.